# A function canonically associated to an irreducible representation in L^2(M) for a Riemannian G-manifold M. Who has seen it?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

The following is my first question here on mathoverflow.

Let $M$ be a closed connected Riemannian manifold with an isometric effective action of a compact connected Lie group $G$. Consider the representation of $G$ on $L^2(M)$ given by $gf(x):=f(g^{-1}x)$, which decomposes into a direct sum of irreducible representations. Let $V\subset L^2(M)$ be such an irreducible $G$-representation. Choose a function $a\in V$ with $||a||_{L^2(M)}=1$ and define a new, $G$-invariant function in $L^1(M)$ by

$v(x):=\intop_G |a(g^{-1}x)|^2dg$, $\quad x\in M$,

where $dg$ is the Haar measure on $G$. Then it is easy to prove (using the Schur orthogonality relations) that the function $v$ is *independent* of the choice of $a$. Indeed, let $u_1,\ldots,u_{dim(V)}$ be some $L^2$-ONB of $V$. Then

$v(x)=\frac{1}{dim(V)}\sum_{i=1}^{dim(V)} |u_i(x)|^2$, $\quad x\in M$.

*Does the function $v$ have a common name?* *Do you know references where such a  construction has been studied?* The map $v$ seems to be a non-trivial function associated to the irreducible representation $V$ in an elementary way, and surely it has been studied or at least mentioned somewhere in the literature.

Thanks in advance for any helpful remarks and references.

Edit I: To get a more concrete grasp of the function $v$, consider the following example. Let $SO(2)$ act on the two-sphere (with standard metric) by rotations around the axis through the north pole and the south pole. Then each single spherical harmonic spans a one-dimensional irreducible representation of $SO(2)$ in $L^2(S^2)$, and in this case the function $v$ associated to such an irreducible representation is just the squared absolut value of the spherical harmonic spanning that representation. The squared absolute value of most spherical harmonics is indeed a non-trivial (i.e. non-constant)  $SO(2)$-invariant function on $S^2$.
More generally, whenever $V$ is one-dimensional, spanned by some function $u$ with $L^2$-norm $1$, then $v=|u|^2$. Note that this implies that every function spanning a one-dimensional subrepresentation of the representation on $L^2(M)$ given above must have a $G$-invariant absolut value. At the moment even that last fact seems non-trivial to me.

Edit II: As a second, easier example, consider the case $M=G$ with $G$-action given by left-multiplication. Then $v\equiv 1$, so it holds

$\frac{1}{dim(V)}\sum_{i=1}^{dim(V)} |u_i|^2 \equiv 1$

for every $L^2$-ONB $u_1,\ldots,u_{dim(V)}$ of an irreducible $G$-rep. $V\subset L^2(G)$.

Comment: Don't you need to pick a $G$-invariant volume form or something to define $L^2(M)$?

Comment: Of course you're right... I tried to make the question as simple as possible and forgot to mention which measure is used to define $L^2(M)$. In this case, it is the one given by the Riemannian volume density defined by a $G$-invariant Riemannian metric. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I think the title of the question, which almost as useful as "Who can answer this question?" should be replaced by a title related to the topic.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and changed the title.

Comment: It's much better now (although "Who has seen it?" is unnecessary in the title).

Comment: If $V$ is non-trivial and irreducible, then the only $G$-invariant vector should be $0$ (since the space of invariant vectors forms a subrepresentation). Unless I'm making some silly mistake, it seems like this function $v(x)$ should be 0 unless $V$ is the trivial representation, since $v(x) \in V$ is $G$-invariant.

Comment: $\nu(x)$ is a real number, not an element of $V$.

Comment: Isn't $v(-)$ a function of $x$, and then an element of $V$? Or am I confused?

Comment: $\nu$ is a function from $M$ to $\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: I think there is no reason why $v$ should be an element of $V$. Since $v$ is $G$-invariant, it could only be an element of $V$ if it were the zero function or if
$V$ were a trivial representation. Moreover, note that
if we drop the assumption that M is compact then the question still makes sense but $v$ is then a priori not an $L^2$-function, so it could never generally be contained in $V$ except in the trivial case $v \equiv 0$. However, the example that I just added to the question shows that there are many situations where $v$ is non-constant.

Comment: See the PhD thesis  Quantisation commutes with reduction
for cocompact Hamiltonian group actions, http://www.math.ru.nl/~landsman/ThesisPeterHochs.pdf

Comment: I looked into it, but I cannot find a relevant paragraph. Can you specify more precisely where I should look in the thesis?

Comment: The evaluation at $x\in M$ gives  a map $\phi$ from $M$ into the dual $V^*$ of $V$; the function $v$ is simply (up to a fixed scalar multiple) the $G$ invariant norm on $V^*$ applied to $\phi (x)$ for $x\in M$; you can define this for any set $X$ on which $G$ acts, in place of $M$.

Comment: The map is equivariant for the action of $G$

Comment: Isn't your function just the sum of squares of an orthonormal basis of V?  (So it doesn't even depend on the G-action.)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly true. That is also the reason why $v$ is independent of the choice of $a$. And indeed, since $v$ is just the sum of squares of an orthonormal basis of $V$, it does not depend on the $G$-action on $V$. But $v$ _does_ depend on the $G$-action on $M$ since the way how $L^2(M)$ decomposes into irreducible $G$-representations depends on the group action.

Comment: Considering the second equation for $v(x)$ that I added to the question, I find it quite remarkable that the squared absolute values of the functions in _any_ $L^2$-ONB of $V$ add up to give _the same_ $G$-invariant function $v$. That seems really unobvious to me, since it is a _pointwise_ equation, while the vectors in $V$ are functions. Of course the values at some $x$ of the functions in an ONB of $V$ change in general when choosing a different ONB. But since $V$ is an irreducible $G$-representation, the sum of the squared absolute values at $x$ do not change...